# Как поместить текст на картинку?

Tags: html, css

У меня проблема, надо поместить текст на картинку, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Надо

## CONQUER

Simple Bootstrap Template наложить на картинку.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul.nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

ul.nav li {
  width: 140px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline;
  /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
  margin-right: 15px;
  /* Отступ слева */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* Рамка вокруг текста */
}

li:after {
  background-color: #49505F
}

.nav a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #383E4C;
  border: 1px solid #646D7C;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #383E4C;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="section1">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="section2">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="section3">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="section4">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="section5">External</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="img/bg-1.jpg" alt="#">
    <h1>CONQUER</h1>
    <h4>Simple Bootstrap Template</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-content">
    <div class="bootstrap"></div>
    <div class="responsive-design"></div>
    <div class="parallax-layout"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: картинку может проще как background поставить у дива, а внутри уже текст размещать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем здесь смысл в абсолютном позиционировании а всё остальное в моём случае просто оформление ...

Делаем некий контейнер и говорим что относительно него будем располагать ваше меню и эту надпись ...т.е пишем в css для `.container{position:relative;}` а меню и надпись располагаем абсолютно т.е `position:absolute`

**Смотрим пример  на полную страницу**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanalei+Fill|Righteous');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Hanalei Fill', cursive;
  color: #00ffff;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: rgba(16, 25, 34, 0.7);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(16, 25, 34, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  padding: 1vh 2vw;
}

ul li a {
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home page</a></li>
    <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">exteernal</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo2tU.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    future metro
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, помогло, теперь разобрался.