# Анимация логотипа в SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Итак, у меня есть логотип клиента, и я хочу анимировать его при прокрутке. Допустим, логотипом является `DANIEL`.

Когда пользователь прокручивает страницу вниз, я хочу, чтобы расстояние между буквами увеличилось, чтобы оно в конечном итоге стало `D A N I E L`.

Я видел, как это можно сделать с обычным текстом, но это будет, как я уже сказал, логотип SVG.  Также логотип должен быть мобильным.

Кто может дать совет, как это сделать?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG Logo animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012725/7394871) от участника  [@DanBilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3698475/danbilly).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012725/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Это на самом деле очень просто. Вам просто нужно следить за событиями `scroll`, а затем обновлять элемент `<text>` в зависимости от того, как далеко вы прокрутили страницу вниз.

Я достиг увеличения межбуквенного интервала, используя атрибут представления `letter-spacing`.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  document.getElementById("mytext").setAttribute("letter-spacing", (window.scrollY / window.outerHeight) + "em");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <text id="mytext" x="300" y="70" font-size="50" text-anchor="middle">DANIEL</text>
</svg>
```

Для других не текстовых элементов, таких как `<path>` и т.д., Вам потребуется немного другой подход. Вам нужно будет физически перемещать их с помощью трансформации.

Вот  демо. Вам нужно настроить его так, чтобы объекты перемещались туда, куда вы хотите.

```js
var EXPAND_AMOUNT = 40;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var scrollPercent = window.scrollY / window.outerHeight;
  document.getElementById("obj1").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 3 * -EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj2").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 2 * -EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj3").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * -EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj4").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj5").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 2 * EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
  document.getElementById("obj6").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(scrollPercent * 3 * EXPAND_AMOUNT)+",0)");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 100">
  <rect id="obj1" x="165" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj2" x="210" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj3" x="255" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj4" x="300" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj5" x="345" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
  <rect id="obj6" x="390" y="25" width="40" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49034184/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: с текстом конечно красивее ... за что и плюс

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Может прикрутишь к своему [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/945397/28748) в качестве бонуса?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT центральные элементы разъезжаются друг от друга с одинаковой скоростью, из-за этого между ними образовывается больший интервал, чем следовало бы. для большей визуальной красоты следует где-то на 1.5 поделить объекты 3 и 4.